# "at most" vs. "at least"

Tags: grammar, phrases, phrase-meaning

I tend to use two phrases randomly with speech but I'd like know to what's exactly the difference between the two?

Let's suppose for example:

- Spend at most $20 on the lunch.
- Spend at least $20 on the lunch.

It seems in both the cases someone will spend $20.

Comment: Well someone *might* spend exactly $20, in either case. But it's much more likely, given those criteria and a bit of human nature, that the first bill will be $19.99, and the second significantly higher.

Answer (score 9):

*At most* means maximum, whereas *at least* means minimum. They are not both going to spend $20 on lunch. One will spend more money and the other will spend less.

Comment: Agreed. In some ways, the two phrases are exact opposites... or mathematically: lunch <= $20 OR lunch >= $20

Answer (score 0):

For 'at least', you may spend the minimum of $20. 'at most', the maximum of $20 and not more than that amount.

Comment: True, but how is OP or anyone else reading this answer supposed to know it's true? If I posted the exact opposite answer, how could someone distinguish between them? Please include a couple of dictionary definitions for max/min in your answer (you may use the [edit] feature). Name the specific dictionary, and link back to it if possible.